# How do you remove the Network icon from Gnome Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, network-manager

Using Gnome Shell, how do I get rid of the Network icon from the top right in the panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the Evil Status Icon Forever extension. Install it by clicking the On toggle switch [HERE](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/99/evial-status-icon-forerver/) and open and edit the extension.js once installed:

`gnomesu gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EvilStatusIconForever\@bone.twbbs.org.tw/extension.js`

You then change the section below by uncommenting what you'd like to hide, in your case "network" so it would look like so:

```
var removeStatusIcon = [
    // 'a11y',         // Accessibility
    // 'volume',
    // 'battery',
    // 'keyboard',
    // 'bluetooth',
     'network'
]
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save.

The reason I don't suggest editing the internal panel JavaScript or modifying the network applets js itself either, is because upon updating either of these could be easily replaced and you would have to reapply your changes.

Comment: Nice extension hack.

Comment: Thanks. After doing this I had to toggle the evil static icon forever extension off/on, and the icon disappeared. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could `/etc/init.d/network-manager stop`. That gets rid of it. To get it to stay gone, you could `mv /etc/init/network-manager.conf /etc/init/network-manager.conf.bak`. Of course, if you're on a wireless connection you might have one heck of a time getting wireless running unless you set it up in /etc/network/interfaces.

l300lvl's answer is so much better

Comment: Of course if one is not using Network Manager, this would be an ideal solution as well.

Comment: Of course... but when is that ever the case? And if network-manager isn't installed then it shouldn't show up anyway ;P

Comment: I prefer this answer since I'm not using network-manager, but I can't remove it without removing gnome.